# basic search function for column of data in database using inputbox (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: javascript, mysql, ruby-on-rails, ajax, postgresql

I'd like to ask for some help creating a feature for my website. Unfortunately I'm not 100% familiar with rails or how it interacts with sql. I'm using postgresql and Rails 3.0 for my application.

I would like to add the following feature: an input box that checks for the existence of a corresponding value in a particular column. More specifically, I would like to have an input box that checks if the same input value exists in the :email column of the :account table.

A user enters an email address into the input box, clicks a button, and depending on whether or not that email address is a value in the :email column of the :account database it would trigger a comment on  the screen.

Unfortunately, I don't know where to implement the sql function (don't know whether this should be located in a view or somewhere else in the code like a controller). Secondly I don't know how to call the code through the button.

Here is my code so far:

Haml

```
  = text_field "member_email" 
  = button_to_function 'Check Member', 'test_email_for_membership()' , :class => "submit"
```

SQL query (not sure where to place this)

```
- if user.where(:email => member_email).exists? == true
  %p user exists
- else
  %p user not found
```

I suspect that I'll have to include some kind of javascript/jquery with AJAX that triggers on button click?

if so here is the ajax:

```
var test_email_for_membership = function(){
    if user.where(:email => member_email).exists? = true
      <p>user is a memeber</p>
    else
      <p>user is not a member</p>
}
```

I'd sincerely appreciate any help that is provided. Finally, thank you so much for taking the time to read this question.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are building a user registration module. Most Rails developers use gems like [Authlogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic), or more advance [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise), but I think Authlogic is a good start.

If you wanna build a user registration from scratch, have a look at [Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up#top).

Answer (score 0):

You could put sql queries at `models/account.rb`

For more info, please take a look at this railscast

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax

Comment: I noticed that the railscast was focused on returning search results (in that case posts that corresponded with the search string). While helpful, this is not necessarily something that I'm after... I just need to check whether a specific email exits in the database... purely validation. Thank for pointing out that it should go into the account model. How can I execute the action in the view?